# jQuery.parseJSON Unexpected token /

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Why `parseJSON` fails when I pass a file? My file is in the variable a and after it I just parse using `parseJSON`

```
var a = "/android/contents/img/uploads/img_2A0.png";

var result = jQuery.parseJSON(a);
```

The error which is giving Chrome is: message: `"Unexpected token /"`

This case raise using droparea.js.

Comment: Well, the value of `a` is not valid JSON. `jQuery.parseJSON` doesn't load data from a URL, it expects the string passed to it to be JSON. I guess you are looking for `getJSON`: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/.

Comment: And for that matter. even if it *did* load data from a URL, why would you think that you could parse a PNG file as JSON?

Comment: some behaviour of droparea.js extension

Comment: See http://json.org - please familiarize with the definition/syntax of JSON

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) about [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/):

> Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript
>   object.

To achieve what you want (getting json from the url) you need to use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) about [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

> Load JSON-encoded data from the server using a GET HTTP request.

Comment: Anyway I manually parsed a like '"' + a + '"'. It is working now. I dont know why droparea needs parse JSON but your solution was tested and working too